# VB.NET Connecting with empty Excel cell - NullReferenceException was cought

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have a problem while I'm connecting with Excel in VB.NET. When I'm looping through the cells to find last non-empty rows inside sheet, when it comes to moment that I'm comparing value of empty cell to "" I recieve error:`NullReferenceException` was caught. Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

There is a fragment of code:

```
   Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
   Dim xlWb As Excel.Workbook
   Dim xlsheet As Excel.Worksheet
   Dim lRow As Integer = 1
   Dim excelFilePath As String

   Using FileDialog As New OpenFileDialog

        FileDialog.Title = "Please choose Excel file with XXX"
        FileDialog.FileName = ""
        FileDialog.ShowDialog()
        excelFilePath = FileDialog.FileName

    End Using

    xlApp.Visible = True
    xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(excelFilePath)
    xlsheet = xlWb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Do While xlsheet.Cells(lRow, 3).value.ToString() <> ""
       lRow += 1
    Loop
```

I tried changing while condition many times to xlsheet.Cells(lRow, 3).value etc. but I always failed - the only way to make it working was by try - catch, but I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it in proper way?

Comment: `Do While xlsheet.Cells(lRow, 3) IsNot Nothing AndAlso xlsheet.Cells(lRow, 3).Value.ToString() <> ""` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

Well, one thing you can do is to use `String.IsNullOrEmpty`, so the `Do` loop would look like this:

```
Do While String.IsNullOrEmpty(xlsheet.Cells(lRow, 3).value) = False
    lRow += 1
Loop
```

But that might get you into an infinite loop, so you might consider using `For Next` instead:

You should first get the last used row:

```
Dim lastRow As Integer = xlsheet.Cells(xlsheet.Rows.Count, 3).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row

'Then use the loop:

For x = 1 To lastRow
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(xlsheet.Cells(x, 3).value) = False Then
        'Do something
    End If
Next
```

And if your main purpose is to get the last used row, you don't have to loop through the rows. You can just use this line:

```
Dim lastRow As Integer = xlsheet.Cells(xlsheet.Rows.Count, 3).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

An empty cell in excel has a value of NOTHING

change your loop to as follows

```
    Do While xlsheet.Cells(lRow, 3).value IsNot Nothing
        lRow += 1
    Loop
```

The row you come out with is the first empty cell, 
`lrow-1` is the last non empty cell in that column

> When I'm looping through the cells to find last non-empty rows inside
>   sheet,

In order to do this you would have to loop through the columns as well as the rows